# Algorithm for intersection of n arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I need to write a function which returns the intersection `(AND condition)` of all the arrays generated in every iteration for an array of queries.

If my query is given by: `query[] = {"num>20", "avg==5", "deviation != 0.5"}` then, `n` runs from `0` to `length of query`. The query is passed on to a function (`get_sample_ids`) which compares the condition against a list of samples possessing certain information. The returned array numbers from `get_sample_ids` are the index of the respective samples.

```
query[] = {"num>20", "avg==5", "deviation != 0.5"}
int intersected_array*;
for n=0:query.length-1
    int arr* = get_sample_ids(query[n]);
    // n=0: [1, 7, 4, 2, 6]
    // n=1: [3, 6, 2]
    // n=2: [6, 2]
end;

Expected output: intersected_array* = [6, 2]
```

I've coded an implementation which has 2 arrays (`arr*`, `temp*`). For every array returned in the iteration, it is first stored in the `temp*` array and the intersection of `arr*` and `temp*` is stored in `arr*`. Is this an optimal solution or what is the best approach?

Comment: The problem is not explained clearly IMHO. For example: "following are arrays returned for every value of n". Where did those array values come from? All you have told us is that they are suddenly "returned". But how were each of those array values derived?

Comment: If you can use a library for an equivalent of Map (a hash) that's O(n). Of course declaring an array of 2^32 chars (if int is 32 bits) having less than 256 arrays to intersect is also O(n).

Comment: We're wondering if using a hash map would bring it to O(n). Thanks.

Comment: @kaylum Sorry about that. Hope I'm clear now. Everyone kindly have a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite efficient but could be tiresome to implement (haven't tried it).

1. Determine the `shortest` array. Benefit of using C is that if you don't know their length, you can use the pointers to arrays to determine it if they are placed sequentially in memory.
2. Make a `<entry,boolean>` hash `map` for the entries in `shortest`. We know the size and if anything it's only going down in next steps.
3. Iterate through an array. Start by initiating the whole `map` to false. For each entry check it in `map`.
4. Iterate through `map` deleting all the entries that weren't checked. Set all the values to false.
5. If there any new arrays left go back to step **3.** with a new array.
6. The result are the keys in the final `map`.

It looks like much but we didn't have to resort to any high complexity measures. Key to good performance is using hash map because of constant access time.

**Alternatively:**

Make the `map` be `<entry,int>`. This way you can count up all the recurrences and don't have to reset it at every iteration, which adds to complexity.

At the end just compare the number of array's to the the values in `map`. Those that match are your solution.

**Complexity:**

Seems like O(n).

Comment: seems like pretty decent implementation, using maps. I thought of a smiliar approach, but couldn't think of using a map. :P

Answer (score 0):

1. First I would sort the arrays in ascending order more easy to preform tasks
2. you could also zero pad the arrays so all the arrays shall be in the same size

[1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6, 7]

[0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 6, 7]

[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0]

like a matrix so you could easily find the intersection

all this shall take a lot of PC run time
enjoy

Comment: If one of the elements is `INT_MAX` or 0

Comment: It is `O(n*log(n))` complexity if we won't assume that we can use CountingSort. I've got a feeling it could be done in `O(n)`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Jquery implementation of @ZbyszekKr solution -

I have `$indexes` as array of arrays for all characters in English alphabets which stores which char is present in which rows. `$chars` is the array of char string I am trying to filter in my HTML table rows. Below method is a part of larger scheme in filtering rows as a user types, when there are more than say 5000 rows in your table.

PS - There are some obvious redundancies, but those are necessary for my plugin I am making.

```
function intersection($indexes, $chars){
    map = {};
    $minLength = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; $minIdx = 0;
    //get shortest array
    $.each($chars, function(key, c){
        $index = getDiffInNum(c, $initialChar);
        $len = $indexes[$index].rows.length;
        if($len < $minLength){
            $minLength = $len;
            $minIdx = $index;
        }
    });
    //put that array values in map
    $minCount = 1;
    $.each($indexes[$minIdx].rows, function(key, val){
        map[val] = $minCount;
    });
    //iterate through other arrays to figure out count of element

    $.each($chars, function(key, c){
        $index = getDiffInNum(c, $initialChar);
        if($index != $minIdx){
            $array = $indexes[$index].rows;
            $.each($array, function(key, val){
                if(val in map){
                    map[val] = map[val] + 1;
                }
            });
            $.each(map, function(key, val){
                if(val == $minCount){
                    delete map[key];
                }
            });
            $minCount++;
        }
    });

    //get the elements which belong in intersection
    $intersect = new Array();
    $.each(map, function(key, val){
        if(val == $chars.length){
            $intersect.push(parseInt(key));
        }
    });
    return $intersect;
}
```